# spring security don't accept my table user

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

please haw can I configure my authentication-provider spring security ..to make him connect on my own table user

```
 CREATE TABLE users
    (
      id serial NOT NULL,
      username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
      "password" character varying(50) NOT NULL,
      enabled boolean NOT NULL,
      authority character varying(50) NOT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT users_username_key UNIQUE (username)
    )
```

it is not working ,I don't know why !!!

```
<sec:authentication-provider>
  <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="DataSource" 
users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select username, authority  from users where username =?" /> 
  </sec:authentication-provider>
```

Comment: Have you looked in the Spring logs?

Comment: haw can I see this option ????

Comment: Depends on the container - look at your logs for Tomcat, JBoss AS, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

"**id** serial NOT NULL,"

It is the reason.

Make **username** as **primary key** instead of **id**.